# What are the rules of 10x10 Draughts? How many pieces are on each side?

Tags: checkers

A Checkers board has 64 (8x8) squares and 12 pieces on each side.
A 10x10 Draughts board has 100 (10x10) squares.

How many pieces are used on the 100 square board?

Answer (score 4):

Each player starts with 20 pieces.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_draughts):

> The gameboard comprises 10×10 squares in alternating dark and light colours, of which only the 50 dark squares are used. Each player has 20 pieces, light for one player and dark for the other, at opposite sides of the board.

You use the first 4 rows (with 5 squares per row being used).